# ByteBuddy - how to save the Java source code?

Tags: byte-buddy, javapoet

It seems quite common to save the .class file with ByteBuddy
[Display generated bytebuddy bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859419/display-generated-bytebuddy-bytecode)

Would it be possible to save the Java source code (.java file) as well in some way?

I found `saveIn(File)` (https://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) can only write the byte code (.class file).

Any help to get this answered much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to reverse engineer source code from a .class file, read about Java decompilers.   (Why doesn't ByteBuddy do this?  For the same reason that it doesn't make coffee!)

Comment: I'm quite new (few hours so far!) to ByteBuddy. Just found as I wanted to automate some code generation. The only one I could find without security issues at present. Pretty sure another person may come across this question. Because not many books found on this topic but quite a useful one.

Comment: Fine.  But why do you expect ByteBuddy to generate source code when its purpose is to generate byte codes?  If you want to generate or (reverse engineer) source code ... you should be looking for / asking about tools whose *purpose* is to do that.  (Didn't you understand my allusion to coffee making?)

Comment: (For the record, ByteBuddy doesn't use Java source code anywhere in its runtime processes.  It generates the bytecodes *directly*.  No source code is involved.  No Java compiler is involved.  There is no source code to "save".)

Comment: Good to know. I liked how ByteBuddy directly gave me the runtime and directly dealt with classes. That makes the runtime more interesting. My use case for this change slightly differ. So perhaps need to go with JavaPoet for this as it has my need covered even though still one vulnerability is posed in the library.

Comment: I did a short research about on ByteBuddy, CGLIB and JavaPoet. Wish there was a book or some sort more learning than just the basics of these libraries. Like the architecture, thinking behind, and intended applications, practical examples sort. Since my time ran out and I had to make some decisions, posted the question here. Because we find the best answers in Stackoverflow, compared to Reddit or what not.

Comment: Also considered using a basic template engine like Thymeleaf or Velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need source code, you'd ideally generate it and compile it. Decompiling class files (there's tools for that too) is normally not equally reliable.